# mysqldb pulls whole query result in one chunk always even if I just do a fetchone?

Tags: python, mysql

So if I do

```
 import MySQLdb
 conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM HUGE_TABLE")
 print "hello?"
 print cur.fetchone()
```

It looks to me that MySQLdb gets the entire huge table before it gets to the "print".
I previously assumed it did some sort of "cursor/state" lazy retrieval in the background,
but it doesn't look like it to me.
Is this right?  If so is it because it has to be this way or is this due to a limitation
of the MySQL wire protocol?  Does this mean that java/hibernate behave the same way?

I guess I need to use the "limit 1" MySQL clauses and relatives if I want to walk through
a large table without pulling in the whole thing at once?  Or no?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In the **`_mysql`** module, use the following call:

```
conn.use_result()
```

That tells the connection you want to fetch rows one by one, leaving the remainder on the server (but leaving the cursor open).

The alternative (and the default) is:

```
conn.store_result()
```

This tells the connection to fetch the entire result set after executing the query, and subsequent fetches will just iterate through the result set, which is now in memory in your Python app.  If your result set is very large, you should consider using `LIMIT` to restrict it to something you can handle.

Note that MySQL does not allow another query to be run until you have fetched all the rows from the one you have left open.

In the **MySQLdb** module, the equivalent is to use one of these two different cursor objects from `MySQLdb.cusrors`:

- CursorUseResultMixIn
- CursorStoreResultMixIn

Comment: thanks, but...  the use_result() method is present, but I don't see it actually changing the timing behavior in my test script.  Does it actually work?

Comment: All the documentation and examples at multiple sites says so, but I haven't measured it myself with Python to be sure.  Could it be that the delay is due to executing the query, before any results are fetched?

Comment: If it caches the whole "select * from table" on the server before sending any results to the client then that's not much help.  I just tried a "select * from table" with no restrictions on a table with 13M rows or so and it just sat there... "select * from table limit 1" by contrast was fast...

Answer (score 0):

This is correct in every other language I've used. The fetchone is just going to only retrieve the first row of the resultset which in this case is the entire database. It's more of a convenience method than anything, it's designed to be easier to use if you KNOW that there's only one result coming down or you only care about the first.

Answer (score 0):

[oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) is an alternative MySQL DB-API interface that exposes a few more of the lower-level details, and also provides other facilities for dealing with large datasets.