# MySQLdb and big queries using CursorUseResultMixIn

Tags: python, database, mysql-python

How can I use the `CursorUseResultMixIn` in **MySQLdb**. The obvious thing to do was:

```
con=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='test', passwd='xx', db='yy')
curs = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.CursorUseResultMixIn)
```

but this gives me this error:

```
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in cursor
    return (cursorclass or self.cursorclass)(self)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Related info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067590/188368) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808150/how-to-efficiently-use-mysqldb-sscursor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MySQLdb.cursors` module uses `CursorUseResultMixIn` like this:

```
class SSCursor(CursorUseResultMixIn, CursorTupleRowsMixIn,
               BaseCursor):

    """This is a Cursor class that returns rows as tuples and stores
    the result set in the server."""
```

That is literally the entire definition of `SSCursor`.

Unless you have a specific need to subclass BaseCursor differently, you could just use `SSCursor` like this:

```
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
con = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'test', passwd = 'xx', 
                           db = 'yy', cursorclass = cursors.SSCursor)
```

PS. There is also a `cursors.SSDictCursor` which returns rows as dictionaries, while storing the result set in the server.

PPS. On Ubuntu 11.10, the `MySQLdb.cursors` module is typically located at `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py`.